# Class template with Eigen templates

Tags: templates, eigen, eigen3

I would like to make a simple template class that holds an Eigen member with dynamic size. I keep getting an error for implicit instantiation. Anyway, what I am trying to make is something like that:

```
template <class T>
class MyTemplateClass
{
public:
    MyTemplateClass(DenseBase<Derived>& eigenObject);
private:
    SomeSortOfTypeHereForDynamicAllocation eigenMember;
}

MyTemplateClass<T>::MyTemplateClass(DenseBase<T>& eigenObject)
{
     eigenMember = eigenObject;
}
```

Comment: Did you really mean `MyTemplateClass(DenseBase<Derived>& eigenObject)` and not `MyTemplateClass(DenseBase<T>& eigenObject)`? Also, what is the exact error? What compiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When declaring a templated member function (or constructor) inside a templated class, you need to add another `template` construct like so:

```
// ...
public:
    template<class Derived>
    MyTemplateClass(DenseBase<Derived>& eigenObject);
// ...
```

When you later want to implement that, you need to write both template-lists in separate `template<>`:

```
template<class T>       // template(s) for actual class
template<class Derived> // template(s) for method
MyTemplateClass<T>::MyTemplateClass(DenseBase<Derived>& eigenObject)
  : eigenMember(eigenObject) // Note: it is usually better to initialize members using the initializer list
{
    // rest of constructor is empty
}
```